# Create, insert text and save a Word doc in C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I've found loads of useful documentation around creating an instance of a word doc, inserting all manner of text and formatting but cannot find anywhere something to save a document that hasnt already been created and opened programmatically.

Essentially I want to create a docx file and fill it with text from a rich text box. Using code Ive found at [How to Insert text in the end of the document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693480/how-to-insert-text-in-the-end-of-the-document) I am able to achieve this if I first create a document. But despite suggestions of using _document.SaveAs() (which doesnt exist - version diff i guess) or .Save() supposedly prompting with a SaveAs dialogue if the file doesnt already exist, I always get a type mismatch error. So this is the working code if i pre-create the file to use:

```
OpenFileDialog SDO = new OpenFileDialog();
SDO.ShowDialog();

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application oWord;
object oMissing = Type.Missing;
oWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
oWord.Visible = false;

oWord.Documents.Open(SDO.FileName);

oWord.Selection.TypeText(richTextBox1.Text);
oWord.ActiveDocument.Save();
oWord.Quit();
```

Now one would assume that removing the lines for the OpenFileDialogue Documents.Open would go some way to saving a new file created in C#, however even with:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application oWord;
object oMissing = Type.Missing;
oWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
oWord.Visible = false;

SaveFileDialog SD = new SaveFileDialog();

SD.Filter = "Word File |*.docx";
SD.Title = "Save File";
SD.ShowDialog();


oWord.Documents.Save(SD.FileName,WdNewDocumentType.wdNewXMLDocument);

oWord.Selection.TypeText(richTextBox1.Text);
oWord.ActiveDocument.Save();
oWord.Quit();
```

Other examples ive seen open the document so that you can save it yourself but i need it saving without any human intervention other than choosing a filename.

Any help appreciated, also the option of third party dlls like spire and gem are precluded so not an option :(

If anyone has a simple example of creating and saving a word doc that didnt exist before the program ran id be much obliged.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[The Microsoft MSDN documentation has tons of useful guides and examples.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd831853(v=vs.120).aspx)

You are going to want to include:

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word;
```

Then declare your application:

```
Word.Application app = new Word.Application();
```

[Declare your new document:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.documents.add.aspx)

```
Word.Document doc = app.Documents.Add();
```

[Add text to your documnet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6b9478cs.aspx)

There are two ways to save these documents:

[Programmatically](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/63w57f4b.aspx)

[Using a save file dialog box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Suddenly Im confused about why i was so confused! Thankyou Mr Rodriguez, i bend before your coding awesomeness.

Comment: Nicely constructed answer

Answer (score 2):

This is the way I do it.

```
app = new Word.Application();

object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
Word._Document oDoc = app.Documents.Add(ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
```

.....

```
app.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2(fileName);
```

Where filename is my desired file name.  When I was originally doing this, I discovered that there were a lot of undocumented (and therefore unsupported) functions.  SaveAs2 is one of them!  But it does work.